# HTML email errors before sending

Tags: meteor

**Error**

email not defined.

I've been trying to debug this and it appears the error is being caused by the code below but I'm not sure why:

```
var html = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.sample-email,data);
```

I'm trying to change my text email to a html template email in Meteor with very little luck. The end goal here is to be able to render the email with the users first name. My emails worked when they where basic text so I assume the problem is with how I'm implementing the templates.

**Packages**
email
meteorhacks:ssr

Path: `server/email.js`

```
Meteor.methods({

    sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
    check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

    this.unblock();

    Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      html: html
    });
  }
});
```

Path: `private/sample-email.html`

```
<template name="sample-email">
<h1>Hey { { name } },</h1>
<h2>This is a simple email rendered with Blaze</h2>
</template>
```

Path: `client/welcomePage.js`

```
Template.welcomePage.events({
  'click .send-email-button': function () {

    var data = {
      name: "Valentin"
    };
    var html = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.sample-email,data);

    Meteor.call('sendEmail',"test@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com","Test",html);

    }
 });
```

Comment: This feels really stupid but try `<template name="sampleEmail">` without the hyphen OR try `Blaze.toHTMLWithData('sample-email',data)`. I suspect it's trying to evaluate `Template.sample - email` as an expression.

Comment: In fact I just verified on the console that `Template.foo-a` returns `Uncaught reference error: a is not defined` - It appears template names cannot be hyphenated: you've either got to take your spouse's name or keep your own!

Comment: Ok, that seem to fix part of the problem but now I'm getting `Uncaught Error: Can't render undefined`

Comment: Are you using SSR? SSR wants to refer to a specific html file (which can be in /private, that's where all my email boilerplate lives). It doesn't use the `<template ...>` syntax at all.

Comment: I have meteorhacks:ssr installed, is that what you mean. If I don't put it in a template how does it get found in private/...

Comment: I use `SSR.compileTemplate('someName', Accounts.getTemplate('someFile.html'))` where `someFile.html` is in `/private`

Comment: Ok, I've kind of got this working. Thanks @MichelFloyd for your help it got me pointed in the right direction and I found the [meteor chef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-email-package/)  example.